# Converting GPS track to turn by turn directions

Tags: routing, navigation, open-source-routing-machine, graphhopper

Working for a client on a tracking package for delivery vehicles, I've been given an interesting requirement.  Over the past several months, we've been collecting telemetry from the vehicles, including lat/lon, speed, heading, and so forth.  The client has asked if we can take an arbitrary track (defined here as an ordered set of lat/lon coordinates) and convert it to a series of turn-by-turn instructions that would result in the same route.

I've been fiddling with OSRM and Graphhopper and both are able to pretty easily turn the points into a polyline and return a set of instructions, but the instructions need a serious amount of reduction in order to be useful to a driver -- for example, traveling down a street for half a mile may result in a dozen instructions that just say "continue on _______ street for 200ft" or whatever the interval between the data points happens to be.

Before I just "brute force" the answer by removing all intermediate points where the street name is the same, I am trying to find an existing SDK or library that can do this for me.  My concern is that blindly removing points may result in generated directions that take a different path, and in this situation even a slightly different path is unacceptable.  At present I'm not even sure what I would call a feature like this, and all I've been able to find when searching are websites that can do this for you, manually, for cyclists and the like.

Edit: Example lat/lon pairs

```
43.059595, -70.753773
43.060723, -70.753812
43.061808, -70.754822
43.062661, -70.755752
43.063645, -70.756604
43.064411, -70.756960
43.065192, -70.757475
43.065901, -70.757851
43.065858, -70.758326
43.065597, -70.758999
43.065250, -70.759751
43.064888, -70.760860
43.064700, -70.761494
43.065337, -70.761810
43.065988, -70.762088
43.066581, -70.762345
43.067072, -70.762563
43.067376, -70.762701
43.067463, -70.762642
43.067521, -70.762206
43.067651, -70.761632
43.067752, -70.761276
43.067868, -70.760781
43.068027, -70.760444
43.068186, -70.760009
43.068403, -70.759593
```

Given to `/route` results in this polyline:

```
mayeGpaznLaFVwEjEiDzDgE`DqCxAaDxAmCfABfBv@`C|@zCfAzEl@xB}B`AaCv@wBn@aBh@{@XUGOsAYqBOiAWaB[eAc@qAg@uA
```

From this json result: https://pastebin.com/qLHrxVPu

Which results in many repeated instructions to continue forward on the same road, for example.  What I'm looking to create, from existing sets of lat/lon points like that, is a simple set of driving instructions saying "go straight on this road xxx meters, turn left here, turn right there..."

I know I can brute force this, but I'm hoping there's something built in somewhere.

Comment: This might have been improved in the latest version. Can you give an example where this is the case with GraphHopper? This should be reproducable with https://graphhopper.com/maps/

Comment: @Karussell I couldn't format all the information correctly in a comment, so I edited the question to add example coordinates and the output from graphhopper's `/route` API.  I really don't know how I can use that maps link to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You can simulate the snapped route with input points (coordinates) and send the resulting link from GraphHopper Maps

Comment: Like https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=43.059595%2C-70.753773&point=43.068403%2C-70.759593 which produces only a few instructions

Comment: Ah, are you using the `/route` end point or the map matching end point `/match`? See https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching or https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/map-matching/

Comment: @Karussell I'm using both.  I used `/match` on each point to snap them to the road network, and then used `/route` on all of those points.  What I am hoping graphhopper (or *something*) can do for me is eliminate all of those redundant "in between" points, as I said in the question.  If I have 20 points on the same road, then a turn with 20 points on another road, I want a list of *three* instructions generated -- "proceed on road for xxx distance, turn onto new road, proceed for xxx distance" -- not 40 instructions saying "proceed 10 meters" as I have now.

Comment: You should use the /match endpoint graphhopper. If you do there will be no additional instructions. Not sure what you mean with '"in between" points'. Assume these 4 points: https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=48.748747%2C7.464437&point=48.750728%2C7.465285&point=48.752511%2C7.466369&point=48.753225%2C7.467023 then the /match end point should return the same instructions like https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=48.748747%2C7.464437&point=48.753225%2C7.467023

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do.  I have a bunch of points recorded from an actual GPS device, they are position reports every 100m/10s/etc.  I want to convert that list of points into a set of turn by turn directions that follows the same course.

Comment: Ok @Karussell here is a graphhopper map link with all the above example points: https://tinyurl.com/y8edtyy5  What I am asking is if there is a built in way for me to eliminate as many of those waypoints as possible **without the route changing**.  Even a slight deviation from the course is unacceptable to the client.

Comment: As I said: the most reliable way is to use the `/match` end point and all unnecessary turn instructions won't be there. btw: Creating a route out of GPS points is not reliable as there can be tiny incorrect values leading in completely wrong routes (which is "calculated away" via `/match`)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a ready-made library to do this with OSRM, but one of the developers outlined an approach in this mailing list posting: https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/osrm-talk/2016-June/001225.html

> My solution for that would remove vias if the way through them is a
>   shortest (duration) path. Technically shortest paths are not unique
>   (think of grid cities). So this might lead to some route modifications
>   that don't change the duration of the route but maybe the actual path.
>
> The way to implement this would be by doing a table query with the
>   vias and removing via j from (i, j, k) if result.durations[i][j] +
>   result.durations[j][k] == result.durations[i][k].

I've implemented this successfully and it works well.